# How to group and filter objects by list objects

Tags: python, django, filter, group-by

I have to get average  grade value by each type of question(many grades at 1 question, 1 question at 1 grade).
Below my code to get just all grades which user got but i don't know **how to "group by" grades by question** and **why my filter doesn't work**(returning 400 bad request)

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def results(self, request):
        user_id = request.data["user_id"]
        survey_id = request.data["survey_id"]
        self_rating_objects = Grade.objects.filter(interview__in=Interview.objects.filter( survey_id=survey_id, target_user_id=user_id))
        serializer = GradeSerializer(data=self_rating_objects,many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here my grade model

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions")
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="grades")
```

And interview model

```
class Interview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    target_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="target_users")
    comment = models.TextField(default='')
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interviews")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I strongly recommend using Jupyter https://medium.com/ayuth/how-to-use-django-in-jupyter-notebook-561ea2401852 on top of django
to get used to the ORM and stuff, very useful to debug.

In your specific case something like this should do:

`self_rating_objects = Grade.objects.filter(interview__survey=survey_id, interview__target_user=user_id)`

When filtering Grade you can call the objects related to it as Interview and access relations to Interview with '__' semantic.

Comment: if you really looking forward to do it as a list (not recommended)
```self_rating_objects = Grade.objects.filter(interview__in=[interview.id for interview in Interview.objects.filter( survey_id=survey_id, target_user_id=user_id)])```
Or similar because actually I do not see Interview's id